# Unit test for S3 PreSigned API

Tags: unit-testing, go, amazon-s3

Im using s3's `GetObjectRequest` API to get the `Request` and use it to call Presign API.

```
type S3Client struct {
    client s3iface.S3API
}

type S3API interface {
    PutObject(input *s3.PutObjectInput) (*s3.PutObjectOutput, error)
    GetObjectRequest(*s3.GetObjectInput) (*request.Request, *s3.GetObjectOutput)
}

type Request interface {
    Presign(expire time.Duration) (string, error)
}

func NewS3Client() S3Client {
    awsConfig := awstools.AWS{Config: &aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-west-2")}}
    awsSession, _ := awsConfig.Get()
    return S3Client{
        client: s3.New(awsSession),
    }
}

func (s *S3Client) GetPreSignedUrl(bucket string, objectKey string) (string, error) {

    req, _ := s.client.GetObjectRequest(&s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(objectKey),
    })

    urlStr, err := req.Presign(30 * 24 * time.Hour)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return urlStr, nil
}
```

Wondering how I can write unit tests for this snippet. So far I have the following but its not working. Would appreciate some help with this.

```
type MockRequestImpl struct {
    request.Request
}

func (m *MockRequestImpl) Presign(input time.Duration) (string, error) {
    return preSignFunc(input)
}

type MockS3Client struct {
    s3iface.S3API
}

func init() {
    s = S3Client{
        client: &MockS3Client{},
    }
}

func (m *MockS3Client) GetObjectRequest(input *s3.GetObjectInput) (*request.Request, *s3.GetObjectOutput) {
    return getObjectFunc(input)
}

func TestS3Service_GetPreSignedUrl(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("should not throw error", func(t *testing.T) {
        getObjectFunc = func(input *s3.GetObjectInput) (*request.Request, *s3.GetObjectOutput) {
            m := MockRequestImpl{}.Request
            return &m, &s3.GetObjectOutput{}
        }
        preSignFunc = func(expire time.Duration) (string, error) {
            return "preSigned", nil
        }

        url, err := s.GetPreSignedUrl("bucket", "objectKey")
        assert.Equal(t, "preSigned", url)
        assert.NoError(t, err)
    })
}
```

Getting the following error : `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`
For line   `urlStr, err := req.Presign(30 * 24 * time.Hour)`. Guessing req is returned as nil

Comment: it is not clear in your test TestS3Service_GetPreSignedUrl where `s` is being created, and where the mock is being passed into `S3Client`. Can you include the full test?

Comment: Added the full test

Comment: mind pasting the full stack trace in the error as well?

Comment: `=== RUN   TestS3Service_GetPreSignedUrl
=== RUN   TestS3Service_GetPreSignedUrl/should_not_throw_error
--- FAIL: TestS3Service_GetPreSignedUrl (0.00s)
    --- FAIL: TestS3Service_GetPreSignedUrl/should_not_throw_error (0.00s)
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
 panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x2 addr=0x0 pc=0x102ca1eb4]`

Comment: I believe `req` is null and so `urlStr, err := req.Presign(30 * 24 * time.Hour)` throws this error

Comment: @maxm Any insights? Im still struggling with this